# Angular 5 multiple routing module

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new in Angular 5 and trying to build an app with client side and admin side. So I did some search and made this:

**AppRoutingModule**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: 'app/website/public.module#PublicModule'
    },
    {
        path: 'admin',
        loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
  })
  export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**PublicRoutingModule**

```
const PUBLIC_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(PUBLIC_ROUTES)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
  })
  export class PublicRoutingModule { }
```

**AdminRoutingModule**

```
const ADMIN_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        data: {
            title: 'Dashboard'
        },
        children: [

        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(ADMIN_ROUTES)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

And I have imported `AppRoutingModule` in `AppModule`, and also imported `PublicRoutingModule` in `PublicModule`, also imported `AdminRoutingModule` in `AdminModule`.

When I run the app, there is no errors but the `HomeComponent` is not been rendered initially.
Can anyone tell what's the problem here? Thank you.

Comment: where did you add your router-outlet? can you paste a snippet ?

Comment: there are many router outlets:
in app.component,html, public.component.html, admin.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For lazy load module, I think you should add components' declarations to their own router module.

Example for `PublicRoutingModule`(same for `AdminRoutingModule`)

```
const PUBLIC_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ HomeComponent ],                       // add declaration
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(PUBLIC_ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PublicRoutingModule { }
```

---

BTW, while debugging routing problems, you should enable tracing to see what really happened during navigation.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Thank you it was helpful. As you suggested but in another way I've added HomeComponent in PublicModule.